# CSS Display Issue - Aligned Divs Height

Tags: html, css

I am having a few issues getting 3 divs to align in a web page. Basically, I have 3 divs along side each other in a 'main' div. I want to set a minimum height on all 3 of the child divs, but have them expand to match the height of the largest of the 3. The crude image below shows the issue.

EDIT - To clarify, I am trying to get the 'Blue' and 'Red' sections (sideMenu, rightMenu and contentDiv) to expand automatically to reach the footer. As it stands now, the central div expands and leaves white space beneath the left and right 'Blue' sections.

[image: Display issue]

My html looks like this -

```
<div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="sideMenu">
            <div class="vertical-menu">
                <a id="uxLink_1" runat="server" href="1.aspx">1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightMenu" id="uxRightMenu">
            <a href="" id="uxRightLink" runat="server"><img alt="" src="" border="0" id="uxRightImage" runat="server"></img></a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentDiv"> 
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="uxContentPH" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerBanner" id="uxFootBanner">
        <center>
        <a href="" id="uxFooterLink" runat="server"><img alt="" src="" border="0" id="uxFooterImage" runat="server" class="footerBannerImage"></img></a>
        </center>
    </div>
```

The CSS is as follows -

```
.mainDiv {
width: 98%;
min-width: 440px;
border: solid 5px black; 
margin-top: -4px; 
border-top: none;
overflow: auto;}

.contentDiv {
min-height: 700px;
height: auto;
font-size: 9.5pt;}

.sideMenu {
height: 100%;
min-height: 700px; 
width: 150px; 
float:left; 
background-color: black;
border-right: solid 5px black;}

.rightMenu {
height: 100%;
min-height: 700px; 
width: 115px; 
float: right; 
background-color: black;
border-right: solid 5px black;
padding-left: 5px;}

.footerBanner {
display: none;
width: 98%; 
float:none; 
background-color: black; 
border: solid 5px black;
border-top: none;
min-width: 440px;  
padding-top: 3px;}

.footerBannerImage {
width: 98%;
height: auto;
min-width: 440px;
max-width: 728px;
max-height: 90px;
min-height: 54px;}

.vertical-menu {
width: 150px;}

.vertical-menu a {
background-color: black;
color: white;
display: block;
padding: 12px; 
text-decoration: none;}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
background-color: #37353d; }

.vertical-menu a.active {
background-color: #438210;
color: white;}
```

Comment: do you want the red divs to fill the white area?

Comment: No, I am trying to get the blue sections to expand to the bottom depending on the size of the red section. Currently the central div is larger than the side divs, making the white space visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%` instead of `px` units for your child `div` tags.
It means if you add `width: 50%;` its width will be half of its parent element width.
So if you want to create something like that picture you should give `width: 30%;` to your side elements and `width: 40%;` to you bigger (center) element.

That should work fine. Also, delete every `min-width` & `max-width` property that you add to your child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it with `flexbox` as well.
I've focussed in the layout only and I've ommited some of your markup:

```css
   
.container {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 height:200px;
}
.container a{
 color:#fff;
}
.mainDiv {
 display:flex;
 flex-grow:1;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.contentDiv {
 flex-grow:1;
 background:#f00;
}

.sideMenu {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 flex-basis:15%;
 align-itens:start;
 background-color: #00f;
 
}

.footerBanner {
 background-color: #000; 
 height:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="sideMenu">
   <a href="#">1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="contentDiv"> 
  </div>
  <div class="sideMenu">
   <a href="#">2</img></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="footerBanner">
  <a href="#">3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

[This](http://algid.com/Flex-Designer) is a helper tool for creating `flexbox` layouts quickly.

Comment: I have just tried this and it doesnt quite do what I need. When the content of the central container (contentDiv) reaches the footer, it continues behind the footer, then onto whitespace below it. The div doesnt expand to fit the text.

Comment: Maybe adding `overflow:auto` might help?

Comment: Someone flagged this as a duplicate question, I managed to find my answer there. Thanks for your time anyway.